# Selecting a set of three distinct objects

Tags: drools, drools-planner

Drools Planner used this to select two distinct objects, ensuring that a **rule did not fire twice** for a given pair of objects. If `o1` and `o2` made a match, it fired only once, not twice for `(o1,o2)` and `(o2,01)`.

```
when
    $stp1  : SubjectTeacherPeriod(  $slno : slNo,
                    $id : id,
                    $period_day_order : period.dayOrder
                    )
    $stp2  : SubjectTeacherPeriod(  slNo > $slno,
                    id == $id,
                    period.dayOrder == $period_day_order
                    )
```

How do I select a set of **three** distinct objects? What is a good selection criteria for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same approach should work:

```
$f1 : SomeFact( ... )
$f2 : SomeFact( id > $f1.id, ... )
$f3 : SomeFact( id > $f2.id, ... )
```

Comment: Took me two looks to "get it".